# How to get only physical drives?

Tags: powershell, script

My example code is below. I don't need drives like the cd rom and what not.

```
$drive = Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName $compName | ForEach-Object -Process {$_.DeviceID}
```

Comment: You might find the output of `Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -Property * | Select-Object -First 1 | Get-Member` to be both interesting and useful.

Comment: if you have PowerShell v3+ and for local only, just use `get-physicaldisk`

Answer (score 4):

Two methods using interface type or media type

First option interfacetype,

```
gwmi win32_diskdrive | ?{$_.interfacetype -eq "IDE" -or $_.interfacetype -eq "SCSI" }
```

Interface type of physical disk drive.

The values are:

- SCSI
- HDC
- IDE
- USB
- 1394

Second option mediatype

```
gwmi win32_diskdrive | ?{$_.mediatype -eq "Fixed hard disk media"}
```

Possible values are:

- External hard disk media
- Removable media ("Removable media other than
  floppy")
- Fixed hard disk ("Fixed hard disk media")
- Unknown ("Format is unknown")

to get phsyical drive

```
gwmi win32_diskdrive | ?{$_.mediatype -eq "Fixed hard disk media"} | % -Process {$_.DeviceID}
```

to get logical drive

```
gwmi win32_diskdrive | ?{$_.mediatype -eq "Fixed hard disk media"} | %{gwmi -Query "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID=`"$($_.DeviceID.replace('\','\\'))`"} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition"} |  %{gwmi -Query "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID=`"$($_.DeviceID)`"} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition"} | %{$_.deviceid}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want only physical drives it's as easy as

```
PS>  Get-PhysicalDisk
FriendlyName               SerialNumber         MediaType   CanPool OperationalStatus HealthStatus Usage           Size
------------               ------------         ---------   ------- ----------------- ------------ -----           ----
Generic USB  SD Reader     x                    Unspecified False   OK                Healthy      Auto-Select 14.49 GB
Samsung SSD 840 PRO Series xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx      SSD         True    OK                Healthy      Auto-Select ...47 GB
ST2000DL003-9VT166         xxxxxxxx             HDD         False   OK                Healthy      Auto-Select  1.82 TB
ASMT 2105                  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx Unspecified False   OK                Healthy      Auto-Select ...51 GB
```

if you want the chain of associators [this could help](https://jrich523.wordpress.com/2011/12/12/using-wmi-to-link-a-disk-volume-to-a-physical-disk-with-powershell/)

```
$diskdrive = gwmi win32_diskdrive

foreach($drive in $diskdrive){
    out-host -InputObject "`nDrive: deviceid-$($drive.deviceid.substring(4)) Model - $($drive.model)"
    ##partition
    $partitions = gwmi -Query "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID=`"$($drive.DeviceID.replace('\','\\'))`"} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition"
    foreach($part in $partitions){
        Out-Host -InputObject "`tPartition: $($part.name)"
        $vols = gwmi -Query "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID=`"$($part.DeviceID)`"} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition"
        foreach($vol in $vols){
            out-host -InputObject "`t`t$($vol.name)"
        }
    }
}
```

Sample Output

```
Drive: deviceid-PHYSICALDRIVE0 Model - ST2000DL003-9VT166
        Partition: Disk #0, Partition #0
                D:

Drive: deviceid-PHYSICALDRIVE1 Model - Samsung SSD 840 PRO Series
        Partition: Disk #1, Partition #0
                H:
        Partition: Disk #1, Partition #1
                C:
        Partition: Disk #1, Partition #2

Drive: deviceid-PHYSICALDRIVE2 Model - Generic USB  SD Reader USB Device
        Partition: Disk #2, Partition #0
                I:

Drive: deviceid-PHYSICALDRIVE3 Model - ASMT 2105 USB Device
        Partition: Disk #3, Partition #0
```